# How can I join a table with an external API using Django?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, python-requests

I have a table in my database where I save the movies viewed by some user. It's something like this:

```
tmdb_id         view_date       user_id
464052          15/02/2021      1
602269          14/02/2021      2
```

The field tmdb_id is the id of the movie in [The Movies Data Base webpage](https://www.themoviedb.org/). I can get the datails of this movie using his API and sending this ID as a parameter.

In Django I have this view:

```py
class MovieViewView(APIView):

    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        queryset = MovieView.objects.all()
        serializer_class = MovieViewSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer_class.data)
```

When I request a GET to this view I obtain something like this:

```json
[
    {
        "tmdb_id": "464052",
        "view_date": "2021-02-15",
        "user": 1
    },
    {
        "tmdb_id": "602269",
        "view_date": "2021-02-14",
        "user": 2
    }
]
```

But I would like to get something like this using TMDB API:

```json
[
    {
        "title": "Wonder Woman 1984",
        "view_date": "2021-02-15",
        "user": 1
    },
    {
        "title": "The Little Things",
        "view_date": "2021-02-14",
        "user": 2
    }
]
```

I know how to get this data individually using python-requests [here](https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/movies/get-movie-details) but I want to know how to join it with my table. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a few options:

1. As per the response above, if you have fields that don't change like the movie title it's probably easier to fetch the title from the API when you insert the movie in the database and set the title, director etc. This is a nice way to ensure that read queries are fast and reliable since you don't depend on the uptime of an external API
2. If you want to display more dynamic data, like rating for example, you will have to make the API call sometimes at read time. My opinion is that you should make the call in the view and hydrate your response there since you use the data for presentation only or define a "title" [property method](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-property-function/) on the model which makes the api call when you use `movie.title` and define a [custom serializer](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/#creating-a-serializer-class) to use it

The second option can also be implemented with a [SerializerMethodField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield)

Comment: Thank you! Second option is better for me because I could get dynamic data like ratings (Actually, the title is an example, I need to get a lot of data from that API in different places in my backend). I appreciate your solution as it put me on the right way. Finally I used `SerializerMethodField ()` [Documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield). With it I can create a field in a ModelSerializer which obtain data from a method. It would be great if you add this to the proposed solution to help other users.

Answer (score 0):

Customize your serializer to display the title of the movie. The best way to do this is to have a title field in the database.